# Hit Test TTreview plus/minus (collapse/expand) icon - Delphi

Tags: delphi, treeviewitem

I am using a TTreeview component in Delphi and I have customized the drag and drop functions.
I start the drag on the mouse down (since it is a custom behavior), but I don't want to start the drag event when the user click on the +/- or expand and collapse icons.

Is there a way to know if the user has clicked on the caption of the node or on the expand/collapse icon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `TTreeView` component includes the [`GetHitTestInfoAt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.GetHitTestInfoAt) method for this purpose.

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  HitTests: THitTests;
begin
  HitTests := TreeView1.GetHitTestInfoAt(X, Y);
  if htOnButton in HitTests then
    //do something
  else if htOnLabel in HitTests then
    //do something else
  else if ......
```

The full list of possible [members](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.THitTest) of the [`THitTests`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.THitTests) set is:

- htAbove
- htBelow
- htNowhere
- htOnItem
- htOnButton
- htOnIcon
- htOnIndent
- htOnLabel
- htOnRight
- htOnStateIcon
- htToLeft
- htToRight

Comment: How can i select the treenode if i click only on the expand/collapse icon? Thank You.

Comment: @tdiop detect the appropiate htXXX. The users won't thank you though.

Comment: Ok, htOnButton and TreeView1.GetNodeAt(X, Y) did the trick. (:

Comment: @tdiop your users will still hate losing their selection though!

Comment: what do you mean by that? Node := tw.GetNodeAt(X, Y), then node.selected := true;

Comment: @tdiop Your users will not appreciate their selection being changed by a non-selecting action. There will also be inconsistency when the user expands/collapses using keyboard.

Comment: Why i cannot refer your name using '@' ?

Comment: @tdiop because the author of a post is automatically notified and so the name is not needed and stripped.

Comment: Back to the selection, yes you are right, but i just run into a user who was complaining about the node does not get selected by clicking on the expand button. :/

Comment: @tdiop That's the normal behaviour for a tree view though. There will be plenty of users that feel the opposite, that won't like the change you propose, in my view. Users aren't always right. Anyway, it's your app, you decide obviously, I'm just offering my opinion.